# Is it possible to use button click event to trigger form submit in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Is it possible in React to use the click event on a regular button component to trigger the click of a hidden form submit button/submission of the form with all the form values and updated index intact?

I have an application with a series of steps (like a wizard) and a form in each step that has its own hidden submit button. When `ButtonNext` (and `ButtonFinal` on the final step) are clicked, is there a way to trigger a click on the hidden form submit button so that `onSubmit` runs and the form values and index value are then sent to the `handleSubmit` function?

I can probably access the hidden submit button with a `data-key` attribute.

EDIT: `ButtonNext` and `ButtonFinal` are direct siblings of the form in the DOM and can't be added to the form.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-styled-flexboxgrid'
import { Form, ButtonNext, ButtonPrevious, ButtonFinal } from './style'

const Application = ({ steps }) => {
  const [currentStepNum, setCurrentStepNum] = useState(0)
  const [previousStepName, setPreviousStepName] = useState(steps[0].step_name)
  const [nextStepName, setNextStepName] = useState(steps[1].step_name)
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(null)

  const handleSubmit = (values, step) => {
    setFormValues(values)
    setStep(step)
  }

  const handleClick = (event, step) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setStep(step)
  }

  const setStep = step => {
    step = parseInt(step)
    setCurrentStepNum(step)

    if (step > 0) {
      setPreviousStepName(steps[step - 1].step_name)
    }

    if (step < steps.length - 1) {
      setNextStepName(steps[step + 1].step_name)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {steps.map((step, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              {currentStepNum == index && (
                <>
                  {step.form.length > 0 && (
                    <Form
                      action="/"
                      fields={fields}
                      onSubmit={(values) => {
                        handleSubmit(values, [index + 1])
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                  {index > 0 && (
                    <ButtonPrevious
                      onClick={event => {
                        handleClick(event, [index - 1])
                      }}
                    >
                      Back to {previousStepName}
                    </ButtonPrevious>
                  )}
                  {index < steps.length - 1 && (
                    <ButtonNext
                      onClick={Trigger onSubmit here}
                    >
                      Next: {nextStepName}
                    </ButtonNext>
                  )}
                  {index == steps.length - 1 && (
                    <ButtonFinal
                     onClick={Trigger onSubmit here}
                    >
                      FINAL SUBMIT BUTTON PLACEHOLDER
                    </ButtonFinal>
                  )}
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Application
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a form element with onSubmit set, then any button within that form by default will submit the form. You could disable this default behavior by defining an onClick function for that button, and calling `preventDefault()` on the passed event.

Comment: Hello. The only issue with this approach is I'm unable to add children to the form component. ButtonNext and ButtonFinal exist as siblings to the form.

Answer (score 4):

Yes! you can do this wich React in a similar way that plained HTML.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {value: ''};

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(event) {
  alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
  event.preventDefault();
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}}
```

This way the **< input type="submit" value="Submit" />** will be your submit button and you just pass the handleSubmit function to form tag, **< form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>**

Comment: Hello. The only issue with this approach is I'm unable to add children to the form component. ButtonNext and ButtonFinal exist as siblings to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in vanilla HTML, which *should* work in React. Clicking the button should automatically trigger the form submission event

```
<button type="submit">...</button>
```